# How can I draw a Google Chart from an associative array in PHP

Tags: wordpress, google-visualization

I have an associative array like this:
`Array ( [1] => 39 [2] => 15.5 [3] => 19.5 [4] => 0 [5] => 0 [6] => 0 )`

The keys are the month names and values are the corresponding values to each key. Months form X-axis while the corresponding values are rendered at top of each bar.

The chart I have to integrate with a WordPress plugin.

The final output looks similar to this:

[image]

This is the first time I will be working with a dynamic Google Chart. I searched for some time but because of my zero knowledge in integrating charts I did not understand exactly where and how to start.

Comment: Subrata, this may help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9971917/how-to-work-with-dynamic-data-and-google-charts take answer from "Andrew Koper". It looks relevant.

Comment: Thanks @Tristup! That's helpful. :) I already went through it. In fact I am trying the solution in a different way. I will share if I succeed .

Comment: This might be more helpful : https://www.webslesson.info/2018/07/create-dynamic-column-chart-using-php-ajax-with-google-charts.html